# Replacing Characters With Other Characters

Tags: bash, sed

I am attempting to make a code that searches on google from terminal by inserting thing into the link. Does anybody know how to replace spaces with pluses so that I can insert that into the link instead of the original search term. I am thinking of using things commands like sed, although I don't understand the formatting of sed.

I am currently using the below:

```
search() {
read F1
a=$F1
b=https://www.google.com/#q=
c=$b$a
echo OPENING:
echo $c
open $c
}
```

The problem is that this requires pluses instead of spaces. I need a way to replace spaces with pluses in the a variable.

Comment: Can you show a sample of variables you are working on?

Comment: Show - don't tell: post the actual excerpt from your `.bash_profile` that's not working how you want

Comment: The line with `a=...` That is a Unicode pretty quote, not a normal `"`.

Comment: @steeldriver It's there.

Comment: @muru I am new to this. What do you mean by Unicode pretty?

Comment: https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/quotes.html

Comment: @muru What should I use to fix this?

Comment: Use normal quotes `"`.

Comment: @muru When I do that, it still comes out as https://www.google.com/#q=“ask unbuntu”

Comment: Works fine for me.

Comment: Okay. I guess my computer is just a failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do this and it works on my computer. Just use this code in your .bash_profile.

```
search() {
clear
echo Type in your search term:
read F1
F=`echo "$F1" | sed "s/ /+/g"`
echo Opening: https://www.google.com/#q="$F"
open https://www.google.com/#q="$F"
}
```

Answer (score 10):

To replace characters in a variable **in the bash shell**, you can use [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

Ex. to replace each space with a plus character

```
$ var='some string    with spaces'
$ echo "${var// /+}"
some+string++++with+spaces
```

or to replace sequences of spaces with a single plus (provided you have enabled extended globbing in the shell)

```
$ echo "${var//+( )/+}"
some+string+with+spaces
```

You can assign to a new variable `newvar="${var//+( )/+}"` or reassign to change the value of the variable directly i.e.

```
$ var='some string    with spaces'
$ echo "$var"
some string    with spaces
$ 
$ var="${var//+( )/+}"
$ echo "$var"
some+string+with+spaces
```

---

Here's an illustration of its use in the context described in your updated question:

Construct a minimal `~/.bash_profile`

```
if [ -r $HOME/.profile ]; then
  . $HOME/.profile
fi

search() {
  read -p 'Please enter a search term: ' searchterm
  c="https://www.google.com/#q=${searchterm//+( )/+}"
  echo "OPENING: $c"
}
```

Then start a new login shell and test it

```
$ bash -l
$ search
Please enter a search term: ask   ubuntu
OPENING: https://www.google.com/#q=ask+ubuntu
$
```

Comment: Whenever I try using this in my .bash_profile, I end up getting line 82: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'

Comment: @TheBean show us what you actually put in your .bash_profile.

Comment: @muru There ya go.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this command:

```
sed -i 's/ /+/g' filename
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure how to use that in context. Could you add an example?

Comment: @TheBean the above command will replace all the spaces in your file with '+'. That's what you want to do, right?

Comment: An example would be `echo $VAR | sed -i 's/  /+/g'`...Please provide an example so Yash Khola can use that.